# When I enter this lines of codes, I keep getting py_var0

Tags: python, function, tkinter, textbox, self

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
name = StringVar()

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title("Are you smart enough?")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand="no")

        self.entry = Entry(root,textvariable=name)
        self.entry.pack()

        enterButton = Button(self, text="Enter", command=self.client_enter)
        enterButton.pack(side="top", fill="none", expand="True", anchor = "s")

    def client_enter(self):

        text = name.get()
        textlabel = Label(self, text=name).pack()

app = Window(root)
root.geometry("1200x600")
root.mainloop()
```

For some reason, when I input a name and press the "Enter" button, nothing shows up.
How can I make it say ("Welcome", name) on Tkinter?

Comment: use `text=name.get()` instead of `text=name`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the variable `text` contains the right value, but you are displaying the `name` (which is a `StringVar`) instead.

Replace this:

```
textlabel = Label(self, text=name).pack()
```

By this:

```
textlabel = Label(self, text=text).pack()
```

To make it say `"Welcome, name"`, change the definition of `text` as such:

```
text = "Welcome, {}".format(name.get())
```

---

Also, `textlabel` becomes useless if you put `.pack()` in its definition. You should be doing it like this:

```
textlabel = Label(self, text=text)
textlabel.pack()
```

Or like this if you don't need to store it in a variable:

```
Label(self, text=text).pack()
```